# How to save value from a "upload.js" to request it in other .js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've tried a lot of things to save the data from "request.responseText" to my var "pdf" that is a url with any file type and then call that variable containing the url into other .js that sends a string containing the rest of the form.

Here is the upload script

```
let pdf;
const uploadFile = (file) => {
  console.log("Uploading file...");
  const API_ENDPOINT = "https://file.io";
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const formData = new FormData();
  request.open("POST", API_ENDPOINT, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      console.log("onreadystatechange request", request.responseText);
      pdf = request.responseText;
      console.log("pdf", pdf);
      
    }
  };
  formData.append("file", file);
  request.send(formData);
};

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  var files = event.target.files;
  uploadFile(files[0]);
});
```

and here is the "general form" which have to recieve the data from the form and send it as a string:

```
  let result = document.querySelector(".result");
  let name = document.querySelector("#form-name1");
  let email = document.querySelector("#form-email1");
  let phone = document.querySelector("#form-phone1");

  // Creating a XHR object
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url ="yourapiurl";

  // open a connection
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);

  // Set the request header i.e. which type of content you are sending
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  // Create a state change callback
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // Print received data from server
      result.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  //Converting JSON data to string
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    name: name.value,
    email: email.value,
    phone: phone.value,
    pdf,
  });

  console.log(data);
  // Sending data with the request - not using it rn only console logs
  // xhr.send(data); - not using it rn only console logs

  //Clearing fields
  document.getElementById("form-name1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("form-email1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("form-phone1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("fileInput").value = "";
}
```

Sorry for any typo not native speaker of English and thanks if read.